# laravel mockery

Tags: php, laravel, юнит-тесты, mock

Есть тест:

```
$client = Mockery::mock(DPDClient::class);
$expectedData = [
    'simple response',
];
$client->shouldReceive('authorize')->andReturn($expectedData);
$this->app->instance(DPDClient::class, $client);
$class = $this->app->make(AuthDPDController::class);
$method = $class->__invoke();
```

И класс:

```
class AuthDPDController
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct(DPDClient $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function __invoke(): JsonResponse
    {
        var_dump($this->client);
        $session = $this->client->authorize(config('dpd.login'), config('dpd.password'));
...
```

var_dump говорит, что я все правильно передал, и `$this->client` это `Mock`. Вот только когда идет вызов authorize, он жалуется, что должно было быть передано два параметра, а я передал `NULL`

Уже весь мозг сломал, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А почему не используете примеры [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mocking) и Config::get вместо config?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я уже не раз перечитал ее, и не въехал где косякнул. А config::get это же просто фасад, разве есть разница?

Comment: тогда не знаю, подозревал что это может быть фасад конфига, а раз нет то делайте отладку вызова метода и смотрите почему именно он там выдает ошибку.